# how to render normals of shape without shaders opengl

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, opengl-es, shader

I am newbie in Computer Graphics. 
I was tasked to draw shape without shaders.
But as I understand from internet SMOTHING and using LIGHTS should be used to draw beautiful shape. But I could not use them since I could not render my normals.
In short, I have 3D vertices, indices, normals. I am using Vertex buffer Object to render vertices and indices. So my code is:

```
        glGenBuffers(3, vertexObjectBuffer);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  vertexObjectBuffer[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * numVertex * 3 , vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        //glGenBuffers(1, &vertexObjectBuffer[1]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexObjectBuffer[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * numIndicies * 3 , indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The question is how to send normals if I use Vertex buffer Object but without shaders?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OpenGL ES 2.x onwards you have to use shaders; no shader = no rendering. All inputs are defined by your shader, so to pass in a normal just set up a new vertex attribute which contains the normal data and pass it in via another call to `glVertexAttribPointer()`. It sounds like you are just starting out, so just get basic shaders working first though ;)

If you are using OpenGL ES 1.1 you don't need shaders, but have to use the fixed function rendering pipeline. You can set per-vertex normals via `glNormal3[x|f]()` if you are specifying single verts (really don't) or `glNormalPointer()` if you are passing in a vertex buffer object.

In all honesty learn shaders; they are not really all that complicated, and learning that will teach you want you need for every modern graphics API so it's a very useful skill to learn.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I got you  :)

Comment: hey, I want to render normals without shaders. Can't I do it with glNormalPointer? I suppose I have new version of openGL

Comment: No; if you are using OpenGLES 2.x you have to use shaders. Unlike desktop OpenGL there is no legacy fallback path.